# How to delete all documents inside of a collection except for one to preserve schema

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I plan the schema for each collection by writing it by hand. If I have 500 dummy records in a single collection, I would like to delete all documents except for one, because when I delete an entire collection, the schema disappears.

Is there a way to delete every document in a collection but leave one behind? Or, to copy a document to a new collection so I can delete the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is "schemaless".  There is nothing except your own code enforcing the names and types of fields in a document.  Each document could be completely different.

Also, you might want to know that a collection will spring into existence the moment a document is written to it.  So, even though a collection doesn't appear to exist when you load the console, that doesn't stop documents being written to it.

Lastly, there is no single operation that can delete an entire collection except one document.  You would have to write code to query all the documents and delete them all individually except the one you want to preserve.  But, based on the things I just said above, that doesn't seem to have the value the you might think.

Comment: This is mostly for my workflow, I understand how it is automatic initialization. For me, it helps to see the visual structure of database so that I can see the variable types of each field and the relationships/IDs. If I have a document with 20 fields it can be difficult to analyze the schema if every document with that schema disappears. If I shouldn't use Firestore to plan my schema, what are some modeling tools that can be used for Firestore that can help me visualize its structure? Or, if I like the Firestore GUI, would you recommend having a firebase debug project and a release project?

Comment: I suggest using a data structure in your code to express the scheme, and use that code as a reference.